# Jsoup can't login to establish cookies

Tags: java, jsoup, session-cookies

So I've read all the jsoup articles on creating sessions and auto logins.  Read the questions on cookie issues.  So using all of these examples I created some JAVA code to login to a specific site.  But everytime I login or try to login, I'm redirected back to the login page.

1. With the loginForm I GET the required cookies
2. I then use the Forms action URL to POST my login info
3. I should then be logged in, but instead its a redirect to login again.  Which I can see in the loginDoc object parse.

Question is, what am I doing wrong in trying to login to this specific site?

```
package com.auction.estimates.utils.scraper;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Connection.Response;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;

public class GatherData {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Response loginForm = Jsoup
            .connect(
                    "https://www.rbauction.com/myaccount?redirect=/home/auth")
            .userAgent(
                    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0")
            .maxBodySize(0)
            .timeout(600000)
            .method(Connection.Method.GET)
            .execute();

    Document formDoc = loginForm.parse();
    Elements forms = formDoc.select("form");
    Element elemForm = forms.first();
    String urlAction = elemForm.attr("action");

    Response login = Jsoup
            .connect(
                    "https://www.rbauction.com" + urlAction)
            .data("_58_redirect", "%2Fhome%2Fauth&")
            .data("_58_rememberMe", "false")
            .data("_58_breakpoint","null")
            .data("_58_login", "myEmail")
            .data("_58_password", "myPass")
            .data("_58_rba-login-submit", "Sign+In")
            .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
            .userAgent(
                    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0")
            .followRedirects(true)
            .method(Connection.Method.POST).execute();

    Document loginDoc = login.parse();
    Map<String, String> loginCookies = login.cookies();

    String url = "https://www.rbauction.com/2006-caterpillar-303-5ccr?invId=4322220&id=ar";
    Document doc = Jsoup
            .connect(url)
            .cookies(loginCookies)
            .userAgent(
                    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0")
            .followRedirects(true).get();

    Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");

    System.out.println("What do we have.");
}

}
```

```html
 <form name="_58_fm" method="post" action="/myaccount?p_auth=rlOiteI3&amp;p_p_id=58&amp;p_p_lifecycle=1&amp;p_p_state=normal&amp;p_p_mode=view&amp;p_p_col_id=column-1&amp;p_p_col_count=2&amp;saveLastPath=0&amp;_58_struts_action=%2Flogin%2Flogin" id="yui_3_4_0_6_1415034856663_348">
  <input type="hidden" value="/home/auth" id="_58_redirect" name="_58_redirect">    
  <input type="hidden" value="true" id="_58_rememberMe" name="_58_rememberMe">
  <input type="hidden" value="null" id="_58_breakpoint" name="_58_breakpoint">
  
  <div class="rba-input-line">
   <label for="_58_login">Email address</label>
   <input type="text" tabindex="1" autocomplete="off" maxlength="75" value="" name="_58_login" id="_58_login" class="rba-input ">
  </div>
  
  <div class="rba-input-line" id="yui_3_4_0_6_1415034856663_347">
   <label for="_58_password">Password</label> 
   <a class="rba-label-link float-right" target="_top" href="/myaccount/forgot-password">Forgot password?</a>
   <input type="password" autofocus="true" tabindex="2" autocomplete="off" maxlength="75" value="" name="_58_password" id="_58_password" class="rba-input rba-form-autofocus">
  </div>
  
  <div class="rba-input-line" id="rba-remember-me">
   <span class="rba-ico-inline-text-24">
    <input type="checkbox" tabindex="3" name="_58_chkRememberMe" id="_58_chkRememberMe" checked="checked" class="rba-input-checkbox">        
    <label for="_58_chkRememberMe">
     <span class="faux-a">Remember me</span> 
      &nbsp;<span class="rba-sprite rba-ico rba-ico-24 rba-ico-24-exclaimation">
      </span>
    </label>
   </span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="button-stack button-stack-horizontal-right hf-bottom-margin">
   <input type="submit" tabindex="4" title="Sign In" value="Sign In" id="_58_rba-login-submit" class="rba-button rba-btn-lvl-1">
  </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: That's a lot of hard coded parameters in the URL for your second step. p_auth looks suspicious. I suggest getting the parameters from the actual form returned from the first step.

Comment: All that p_auth stuff was from the action URL.  Just a copy/paste from the Form.  The parameters were below, 3 hidden and 2 visible.

`    .data("_58_redirect", "%2Fhome%2Fauth&")
     .data("_58_rememberMe", "false")
     .data("_58_login", "myEmail")
     .data("_58_password", "myPass")
     .data("_58_rba-login-submit", "Sign+In") `

Comment: If you look at your source and the form HTML you added, p_auth is different between the two. That's why I suspect it is tied to the session and you should get the action URL from the form returned by the first step.

Comment: @Imz Thanks for the comments.  Good point I added the code to parse for the form action, but still the same result. In Debug the request object looks good I can see all the data and cookie info from the GET.  But still drops me back onto the login page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code gives me

```
HTTP error fetching URL. Status=404, URL=https://www.rbauction.com/home/auth&
```

If you change only:

`.data("_58_redirect", "%2Fhome%2Fauth&")` for `.data("_58_redirect", "%2Fhome%2Fauth")` (without the trailing ampersand)

It works fine!

If it doesn't, check your user/pass.

Comment: Thanks that was a typo in my copy paste, still same issue.  I did get around this but it was a pain.

Comment: It worked fine for me. I actually created a test account into the site and I achieved to autologin...

Comment: Can you paste the code you used for the auto login? Mine still re-directs me back to the login form after I login then try to access,  https://www.rbauction.com/2006-caterpillar-303-5ccr?invId=4322220&id=ar . Also after the login my cookie Map goes from 11 objects to 4.

Comment: Sure, I've just rerun this [code](http://pastebin.com/Lirfttiv) (only replace with your user/pass) and has printed this `Sold for 13000 USD on Oct 30, 2014 in Hobbs, NM, USA`

Comment: Yea your code works fine, for some reason I decided in my email address to use %40 instead of just an @ symbol. Trying to make it html safe I guess.  Don't code at 1am is the lesson I guess.  Thank you for the extra set of eyes on it. And with the typo on the auth.

Answer (score 0):

So I was not able to get the auto login working at all.  But this data scrape would probably only happen bi-weekly.  So to get around the issue I logged in with Mozilla and extracted all my current cookies for rbauctions.com.  I then tried just setting the JSESSIONID and USER and PASS cookies.  That failed as well.  So I manually copied and pasted all 31 cookies and their content into a HashMap.

```
Map<String, String> loginCookies = new HashMap<String, String>();
    loginCookies.put("COOKIE_SUPPORT", "true");
    loginCookies.put("__CT_Data", "gpv=9&apv_9545_www09=9");
    loginCookies.put("WRUID", "0");
    etc......
```

After that I was able to access the site and scrap my data.  Its not ideal but at least I can get my data.